# Presenter (August LP205R) doesn't work

Tags: 14.04

I recently bought a presenter with laser pointer (August LP205R), but it doesn't seem to work with Ubuntu [14.04](/questions/tagged/14.04). The remote control seems to work, as the little receiver flashes whenever I press one of the buttons, but the presentation (pdf in presentation mode) doesn't react. Any ideas?

`xinput`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer            id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse            id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ RF 2.4G  RF 2.4G                      id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ HD WebCam                                 id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Acer WMI hotkeys                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ RF 2.4G  RF 2.4G                          id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 1d57:83ed Xenta 
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 0489:e04e Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f2:b3d6 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The `Xenta` entry goes away when I remove the USB-device. Nothing seems to change in the output of `xinput`.

`xev`:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
root 0xbd, subw 0x0, time 7322246, (-153,412), root:(634,464),
state 0x10, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
root 0xbd, subw 0x0, time 7322478, (-153,412), root:(634,464),
state 0x11, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

The slide left/slide right buttons don't provoke any reaction, neither does the screen on/ screen off, this one should turn powerpoint on and off, I think.

Comment: Please post the output of  `xinput`

Comment: I presume, it's connected through USB. Can you post the output of `lsusb` too, please?

Comment: edited in the original post.

Comment: Can you run `xev` and then press sequentially all the buttons of the presenter and update your post with the output if any? The entries of the presenter in `xinput` seems to be `15` and `16` (both called `RF 2.4G  RF 2.4G`)  https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1196793

Comment: Please run these commands: `wget 'http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/keytouch/getscancodes/getscancodes%201.0/getscancodes-1.0.tar.gz?r=http%3A%2F%2Fkeytouch.sourceforge.net%2Fdl-getscancodes.php&ts=1412723944&use_mirror=kent' -O getscancodes-1.0.tar.gz` and then 
`tar -xvzf getscancodes-1.0.tar.gz` and then 
`cd getscancodes/` and then
`make`

Comment: When you're done without errors, then run `sudo ./getscancodes /dev/input/event16` then  `sudo ./getscancodes /dev/input/event15` pressing all the buttons sequentially during both commands,  and post the output of both. (please include the button you pressed in each line of output)

Comment: If  the commands above are so complicated for you, please, update your post with the output of this command `dmesg | tail`, running it after pressing all the buttons. Remove any sensitive info on the output.

Comment: @HansFritz: I don't have any feedback from you. Are you there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [August LP205R on Ubuntu GNOME 15.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/660593/august-lp205r-on-ubuntu-gnome-15-04)