# August LP205R on Ubuntu GNOME 15.04

Tags: drivers, usb, 15.04, udev, input-devices

[Similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/605899/presenter-august-lp205r-doesnt-work) have been asked before, but there were no answers. I cannot comment there, nor I have an answer, therefore I don't see other option but to ask again.

I have a USB laser presenter August LP205R that does not work on GNOME Ubuntu 15.04, but works OK on Windows with both PowerPoint & PDF presentations. Here are the outputs asked for in the previous link:

`xinput`

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ RF 2.4G  RF 2.4G                          id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_HD               id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ RF 2.4G  RF 2.4G                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

`lsusb`

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:64ad Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1d57:83ed Xenta 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:07e6 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`xev` gives output only on Start/End slideshow button:

```
KeyPress event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0xac, subw 0x0, time 14518987, (642,556), root:(643,609),
    state 0x10, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0xac, subw 0x0, time 14519138, (642,556), root:(643,609),
    state 0x11, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

I even tried the `getscancodes` and `dmesg | tail` recommended previously:

```
~/Downloads$ tar -xvzf getscancodes-1.0.tar.gz
getscancodes/
getscancodes/getscancodes.c
getscancodes/getscancodes
getscancodes/Makefile
getscancodes/getscancodes.o

~/Downloads$ cd getscancodes/

~/Downloads/getscancodes$ make
gcc -O2 -Wall   -c -o getscancodes.o getscancodes.c
gcc -o  getscancodes getscancodes.o

~/Downloads/getscancodes$ sudo ./getscancodes /dev/input/event16
[sudo] password for : 
getscancodes: No such file or directory

~/Downloads/getscancodes$ cd ..

~/Downloads$ sudo ./getscancodes /dev/input/event16
sudo: ./getscancodes: command not found

~/Downloads$ cd getscancodes/

~/Downloads/getscancodes$ dmesg | tail
[ 8630.569019] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d57, idProduct=83ed
[ 8630.569043] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[ 8630.569059] usb 1-1.2: Product: RF 2.4G 
[ 8630.569073] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: RF 2.4G 
[ 8631.425965] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[ 8631.425982] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[ 8631.720489] input: RF 2.4G  RF 2.4G  as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/0003:1D57:83ED.0001/input/input11
[ 8631.776680] hid-generic 0003:1D57:83ED.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [RF 2.4G  RF 2.4G ] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2/input0
[ 8631.778126] input: RF 2.4G  RF 2.4G  as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.1/0003:1D57:83ED.0002/input/input12
[ 8631.833351] hid-generic 0003:1D57:83ED.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [RF 2.4G  RF 2.4G ] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2/input1

~/Downloads/getscancodes$
```

I was wondering if somebody could help me figure out if & how should I update or make a new `*-keyboard.hwdb` file from the data above, as mentioned here:

- [Xubuntu - Logitech presenter works only partialy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/565555/xubuntu-logitech-presenter-works-only-partialy)
- [How do I change the keymap of a single device (Logitech presenter)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69804/how-do-i-change-the-keymap-of-a-single-device-logitech-presenter)

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Looking in web for similar device point me that your device is `1d57:83ed Xenta` and it create two input devices (a mouse and a keyboard) labeled as `RF 2.4G  RF 2.4G` with `id=14` & `id=13` from your commands output.
- `getscancodes` was already created in `~/Downloads/getscancodes` folder but `/dev/input/event16` is not the corresponding event device file. You can find related event file using:

  ```
  xinput --list-props 14
  xinput --list-props 13
  ```

  Than run `./getscancodes /dev/input/eventXX` for both event files and try all keys.
- If `getscancodes` didn't work, there a standard tool from Ubuntu  repository. Give it a try:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install evtest
  sudo evtest
  ```
- The method explained in [How do I change the keymap of a single device (Logitech presenter)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69804/how-do-i-change-the-keymap-of-a-single-device-logitech-presenter) is outdated.

  So follow [Xubuntu - Logitech presenter works only partialy](https://askubuntu.com/a/576012/26246) which have same instructions mentioned as comment/header in `/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb`