# How to set up a wireless presenter?

Tags: 14.04, libreoffice, remote

I'm trying to set up my LP205R wireless presenter. I looked all the forums and it seems like no body had success doing it. A list of questions I have tried are at the end.

I tried `getscancodes` and `evtest` and got no response from the device, it seems like it has to be set up from scratch? I also tried `lirc` but it did not work. I do not have a wide notion of linux so maybe you can guide through it. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

[Presenter (August LP205R) doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/605899/presenter-august-lp205r-doesnt-work)

[August LP205R on Ubuntu GNOME 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/660593/august-lp205r-on-ubuntu-gnome-15-04)

[How do I change the keymap of a single device (Logitech presenter)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69804/how-do-i-change-the-keymap-of-a-single-device-logitech-presenter)

[Xubuntu - Logitech presenter works only partialy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/565555/xubuntu-logitech-presenter-works-only-partialy/576012#576012)

[Wireless presenter (August LP206M)](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2104107)

[My Ubuntu doesn't recognize my wireless presenter (works through USB)](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+question/135206)